# How to have control over the section names in the SXA Toolbox?

Tags: sxa

I have a project with a defined folder structure for the renderings. I am in the process of adding `SXA` support and would like to create `SXA Toolbox` sections containing these renderings.

By default, Sitecore chooses the name of the section based on the parent folder a rendering is in, but I prefer not to use this as the defined folder structure gives meaningless names. I also would prefer not to change the defined folder structure.

There is a setting [Group renderings in sections according to Available Renderings items in the site](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/restructure-the-sxa-toolbox.html) that changes this to use the Available Renderings name, however, this is applied for the whole site. As this would affect other sections I cannot make use of this setting.

Is there another way to configure the Toolbox section names, for example with a pipeline processor?

Comment: I don't understand why the option with the available renderings is not ok? Try sticking to ootb features, especially when it's nothing critical.

Comment: As I am working on a library project, I would not like to enforce this upon the users of the library (as this is for the whole site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a solution based on Joost's answer. It always returns true for `GetOrdereredRenderings` as that way Sitecore will always call the `GetOrderedRenderings` method. Then the checkbox is actually checked an the original logic is mimicked if it is not.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyProject.Foundation.Framework.Extensions;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Models;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Service;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Presentation;
using Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Repositories;

namespace MyProject.Foundation.Framework.Sxa
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Custom implementation of a IAvailableRenderingsOrderingService, which renames sections which contain MyProject renderings.
    /// </summary>
    public class MyProjectToolboxSectionRenamer : IAvailableRenderingsOrderingService
    {
        private readonly AvailableRenderingsOrderingService originalService;

        public MyProjectToolboxSectionRenamer(IPresentationContext presentationContext, IMultisiteContext multisiteContext, IContentRepository contentRepository)
        {
            originalService = new AvailableRenderingsOrderingService(presentationContext, multisiteContext, contentRepository);
        }

        public bool IsOrderingApplicable(Item siteItem)
        {
            //Always return true, as only then Sitecore calls GetOrderedRenderings.
            return true;
        }

        public IList<AvailableRenderingEntry> GetOrderedRenderings(Item siteItem, IList<Item> renderings = null)
        {
            if (renderings == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var orderedRenderings = GetDefaultOrderedRenderings(siteItem, renderings);
            ApplyMyProjectNames(orderedRenderings);
            return Reorder(orderedRenderings).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the default ordered renderings (as Sitecore would retrieve it), do the actual check on whether or not ordering is applicable, as we skipped that in our implementation of IsOrderingApplicable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="siteItem"></param>
        /// <param name="renderings"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IList<AvailableRenderingEntry> GetDefaultOrderedRenderings(Item siteItem, IList<Item> renderings)
        {
            return originalService.IsOrderingApplicable(siteItem)
                ? originalService.GetOrderedRenderings(siteItem, renderings) 
                : GetRenderingsBasedOnParentName(siteItem, renderings);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// An implementation of building up the renderings with section names based on the parent nodes, based on Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Dialogs.SelectRenderingForm
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="siteItem"></param>
        /// <param name="renderings"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IList<AvailableRenderingEntry> GetRenderingsBasedOnParentName(Item siteItem, IList<Item> renderings)
        {
            List<IGrouping<string, Item>> renderingsByParent = renderings.GroupBy(i => i.Parent.DisplayName).OrderBy(g => g.Key).ToList();
            var availableRenderings = new List<AvailableRenderingEntry>();
            foreach (var renderingByParent in renderingsByParent)
            {
                foreach (var rendering in renderingByParent.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayName))
                {
                    availableRenderings.Add(new AvailableRenderingEntry()
                    {
                        Order =  availableRenderings.Count,
                        RenderingItem = rendering,
                        SectionName = renderingByParent.Key
                    });
                }
            }
            return availableRenderings;
        }

        private void ApplyMyProjectNames(IList<AvailableRenderingEntry> orderedRenderings)
        {
            var myProjectRenderings = orderedRenderings.Where( ... Filter on only MyProject renderings ... );

            foreach (var rendering in myProjectRenderings)
            {
                rendering.SectionName = ... Determine custom name ...;
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<AvailableRenderingEntry> Reorder(IEnumerable<AvailableRenderingEntry> orderedRenderings)
        {
            return orderedRenderings
                .OrderBy(x => x.SectionName)
                .ThenBy(x => x.RenderingItem.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could override and change the `GetOrderedRenderings` method in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Service.AvailableRenderingsOrderingService` to calculate the `SectionName` differently.

In the configuration the `AvailableRenderingsOrderingService` is registered as follows:

```
<register serviceType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Service.IAvailableRenderingsOrderingService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing" implementationType="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Service.AvailableRenderingsOrderingService, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing" lifetime="Singleton" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.config"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `GetOrderedRenderings` only is called when having the 'group by section name' checkbox checked. After looking into `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Dialogs.SelectRenderingForm` this behaviour is confirmed...